# How to treat single column with both continuous and categorical data for ML model

Tags: classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-extraction

I am working on financial data where I have a feature(column) with 90% values between 0-1000 (continuous) and 10% values as -1, -2 and -9. (default values)

Default value definition:
-1: data not available
-2: Partial data available
-9: Data available but its too old

My question - As default value are categorical in nature, how should I treat the 10% default cases to separate them from 90% continuous data points, Should I set them to values like "-9999", "-999" ,"-99" or any other suggestion?

I want to use to data to train classification model

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the categorical and continuous values as a single continuous feature, then there is an implied numerical relationship between the values used categorically and the continuous values. So unless there is a real basis for such a relationship, then it's unlikely to achieve good results.

One way to handle this sort of data is to split it into two features - one to handle the continuous values and one to handle the categorical defaults. Then one-hot encode the defaults. Your data points with continuous values would have 0's for all the one-hot encoded columns. The continuous feature would need to be set to a (single) default value for all data points with categorical values.

For instance, if the data is:

| ID | Feature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 250 |
| 3 | -1 |
| 4 | -2 |
| 5 | -9 |
| 6 | 75 |
| 7 | -2 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | -1 |
| 10 | 125 |

This could be encoded as:

| ID | F_continuous | F_-1 | F_-2 | F_-9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 250 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 75 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 125 | 0 | 0 | 0 |